# Hibernate does not update the records?

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate with spring. in daoImpl i have a single method that updates records in two tables as below.

```
Query queryOne = session.createQuery("some update query")

Query queryTwo = session.createQuery("some update query")

queryOne.executeUpdate();
queryTwo.executeUpdate();
```

but the proble is, the first query is updating properly. but the second query is not updating even though query is firing on console. my question is is it right approach to write create two queries in same session? Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: It should work. You must have a problem in your second query. Note that it's unusual to perform update queries using Hibernate. The usual way is to manipulate the persistent entities, and let Hibernate do the modifications for you.

Comment: Hi Nizet, Thanks for your reply. i am doing one more thing. before update i am calling some save method on some other table. after i am calling above two queries on different tables. please help me.

Comment: If one update succeeds and not the other, that means that it's not a problem of rollback of the transaction. And you see the query in the logs, so it's executed. So your query must be wrong. WHat does the call to executeUpdate return? If it's 0, then it means that the query has been executed, but didn't update anything.

Comment: Hi Nizet, when save operation is done then second query does not update even though it is firing. if the list is empty to be saved, then save operation is not done, then it updates properly.

Comment: Are the 2 queries dependent on each other?Can you change the order of both and execute them?